# Possible motif behind using pass after raise in Python exception handling

Tags: python, exception

```
try:
  [code]
except Exception:
  [something]
  raise
  pass
```

Above code snippet looks a bit weird, doesn't it? Am I missing something? Why is there a raise and a pass following it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a NOP. It does nothing. Nothing at all. No clue why they left it there, because it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

seems like initially it was just

```
except Exception:
    pass
```

somebody just forgot to remove it after adding exception handling

Comment: Quite possible, seems odd though, considering that it's some serious code